# MatLab find column number of text cell array

Tags: matlab

I have a cell data type matrix containing a header and a large number of rows.

sample data:

```
set         press       dp
32.7045     17.805965   123.75047
32.690094   17.80584    123.74992
32.6232     17.815094   123.790115
```

I am trying to find the index of a specific column using the strcmp command to search through the all the data.

```
dpCol = strcmp([data{:}], 'dp')
```

This always returns

```
dpCol =

     0
```

Am I using the data cell type wrong or something? Thank you!

Comment: To understand why your code is not working, take a look at the intermediate result `[data{:}]`. This is definitely not what you want.

Comment: Tried other options such as `[date{1,:}]` but that didn't help...

Answer (score 2):

Try using cell notation to yield just the 1st row, EG:

```
data(1,:) = {'set','press','dp'}
```

instead of unpacking<sup>*</sup> the entire cell array since [`strcmp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) can operate on cell arrays.

```
>>> data = {'set'         'press'       'dp'
32.7045     17.805965   123.75047
32.690094   17.80584    123.74992
32.6232     17.815094   123.790115}

data = 

    'set'        'press'      'dp'      
    [32.7045]    [17.8060]    [123.7505]
    [32.6901]    [17.8058]    [123.7499]
    [32.6232]    [17.8151]    [123.7901]

>>> col_idx = strcmp(data(1,:),'dp')

col_idx=

     0     0     1
```

Then return the `dp` using the logical indices and [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html)...

```
>>> dp = cell2mat(data(2:end,col_idx))
dp =

  123.7505
  123.7499
  123.7901
```

or unpack<sup>*</sup> and concatenate the comma separated list

```
>>> dp = [data{2:end,col_idx}]

dp =

  123.7505  123.7499  123.7901
```

As an alternative try [`cell2struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2struct.html).

```
>>> datastruct = cell2struct(data(2:end,:),data(1,:),2)
datastruct = 

3x1 struct array with fields:

    set
    press
    dp
```

Then `dp` is ...

```
>>> dp = [datastruct.dp]

dp =

  123.7505  123.7499  123.7901
```

<sup>*</sup> Using the colon operator inside curly braces unpacks an cell array into a comma separated list. Using square brackets horizontally concatenates the comma separated list which returns a character array `set   pressdp{{{` since the first item in the list is a character array. The garbage characters between and after `'set'`, `'press'` and `'dp'` are caused by reading the doubles as `char`. IE: `char(32.7045)` is the ASCII equivalent of whitespace. The arrays always get unpacked as column.

Comment: Thank you Mark, does exactly what I needed. Another issue did arise giving me the following error `Error using cat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in cell2mat (line 83)
            m{n} = cat(1,c{:,n});

Error in OpenFile (line 38)
dp = cell2mat(data(2:end,col_idx))`   Tried replacing col_index with the column number, doesn't help either.

Comment: The alternative option does return results but they are all in the same cell. All the results are concatenated one after the other.